# How to compute each cell as a function of index and column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a use-case where it naturally fits to compute each cell of a `pd.DataFrame` as a function of the corresponding index and column i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.empty((3, 3))
data[:] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=[1, 2, 3], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(df)
>    a   b   c
>1 NaN NaN NaN
>2 NaN NaN NaN
>3 NaN NaN NaN
```

and I'd like (this is only a mock example) to get a result that is a function `f(index, column)`:

```
>    a   b   c
>1  a1  b1  c1
>2  a2  b2  c2
>3  a3  b3  c3
```

In order to accomplish this I need a way different to [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) where the lambda gets the coordinates in terms of the index and col i.e.

```
def my_cell_map(ix, col):
    return col + str(ix)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible use numpy - add index values to columns with broadcasting and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = df.columns.to_numpy() + df.index.astype(str).to_numpy()[:, None]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
    a   b   c
1  a1  b1  c1
2  a2  b2  c2
3  a3  b3  c3
```

EDIT: For processing by columns names is possible use `x.name` with index values:

```
def f(x):
    return x.name + x.index.astype(str)

df = df.apply(f)
print (df)
    a   b   c
1  a1  b1  c1
2  a2  b2  c2
3  a3  b3  c3
```

EDIT1: For your function is necessary use another lambda function for loop by index values:

```
def my_cell_map(ix, col):
    return col + str(ix) 

def f(x):
    return x.index.map(lambda y: my_cell_map(y, x.name))

df = df.apply(f)
print (df)
    a   b   c
1  a1  b1  c1
2  a2  b2  c2
3  a3  b3  c3
```

EDIT2: Also is possible loop by index and columns values and set by `loc`, if large DataFrame performance should be slow:

```
for c in df.columns:
    for i in df.index:
        df.loc[i, c] = my_cell_map(i, c) 
print (df)
    a   b   c
1  a1  b1  c1
2  a2  b2  c2
3  a3  b3  c3
```

Comment: @anky - Opps, I swap it.

Comment: Thank you but the example was a mock for illustrative purposes, I need a solution for the general case. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding and I fixed the question accordingly.

Comment: @SkyWalker - Added next 2 solutions.

Comment: thank you! fantastic! SO doesnt let accepting an answer so fast :)